# Interpreting documentation on arrays (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

> "if T is an array type, every element of the array is
> default-initialized"

Am I  misunderstanding something because as we all know  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

> By default, regular arrays of local scope (for example, those declared
> within a function) are left uninitialized. This means that none of its
> elements are set to any particular value; their contents are
> undetermined at the point the array is declared.
>
> ...
>
> The initializer can even have no values, just the braces:
> This creates an array of five int values, each initialized with a value of zero

How is the first source accurate and
where can I find more credible documentation that addresses this behavior of array default initialization?

Comment: cppreference is usually pretty credible, the next step up is the standard itself: but the current draft's reference for [default initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7) isn't any different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the whole thing. I numbered them:

> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> 1. if T is a non-POD (until C++11) class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;
> 2. if T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized;
> 3. otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

It's a recursive statement. Every element in the array is default-initialized. What that means depends on the element type. If the element type is something 1. would apply to, then a default constructor is called for each element. But if the element type is, say, `int`, then 3. happens. It's left with an indeterminate value.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't realize it was supposed to be read recursively. But I dont think the statement mentions when element type for array (ex. integer) will become default initialized to 0? such as int array[2] = {1}

Comment: @csguy That would be zero-initialization, not default-initialization. And zero-initialization is explained here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

Comment: im understanding now, but the syntax for default initialization is             
" T object;" so this means arrays are objects?

Comment: @csguy "Object" in C++ doesn't mean what most people think it means (and most people think the term "object" only refers to instances of a class.) Almost everything that has an address and a size is an object. A simple `int` variable for example is an object, and so is an array of `int` (the array itself is an object, and its elements are subobjects.) See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

Comment: if im not mistaken, "when element type for array (ex. integer) will become default initialized to 0? such as int array[2] = {1}" should refer to aggregate initialization, not zero initialization which is for static objects?

Comment: @csguy For braced initializers, you get "list-initialization", which is defined here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization.

Comment: @csguy the word "object" means different things in different programming languages. In Java, for example, arrays are also  objects.

Answer (score -2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/new-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019

new Operator is Reference MSDN.

Basically, inside the new operator, it consists of a function to be allocated and initialized by malloc.
This is a function that is lapping with a new function.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialise anything. Also, `new` is not required to call `malloc`.